# VarType for user defined type

Tags: vba, user-defined-types

I have some user-defined objects in my VBA code and was wondering if there is a way to check was object type something is.  Some thing like

```
Dim myObject as Variant
Set myObject= New Employee

     If(myObject isType Employee)
           Do Something
      Else
           Do something else
```

I was thinking the VarType() function, but it apparently won't work for user defined types.  Is there something else I can use?

Comment: by 'user-defined objects' you mean 'classes'?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities to do so. The following code should explain everything. See some additional comments inside:

```
Sub qTest()

    Dim myObject As Variant
    Set myObject = New Employee

    'return results to Immediate
    Debug.Print TypeName(myObject) '>> will return class name
    Debug.Print TypeOf myObject Is Employee '>>will return true

    'using with 'if statements', both will return true 
    If TypeName(myObject) = "Employee" Then
        MsgBox "OK"
    End If

    If TypeOf myObject Is Employee Then
        MsgBox "OK"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `TypeOf`. Using your example above, it can be used as follows:

```
Dim myObject as Variant
Set myObject= New Employee

If TypeOf myObject is Employee Then
    Do Something
Else
    Do SomethingElse
End If
```